# Scanner input data types

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to write a test class that will do the following:

- a. Let the user input an integer and display it.
- b. Let the user input a float value and display it.
- c. Let the user input his/her name (no white spaces) and display the
  name as: `“Hello <name>, welcome to Scanner!”`
- d. Let the user input a character and display it.
- e. Let the user input any string (with white spaces) and display it.

***My questions is, how can I simply scan just a `Character` and display it? And in number 2, How can I input a `String` with white spaces and display it? (letters "d" and "e")***

I've searched around, but I cannot find the simplest solution (since I'm new to Java and programming).

Here is my code so far:

> ```
> package aw;
>
> import java.io.PrintStream;
> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class NewClass1
> {
>   public static void main(String[] args)
>   {
>       int num;
>       double num2;
>       String name;
>       char c;
>           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>           PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
>
>       //for integer
>       System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
>       num = sc.nextInt();
>       ps.printf("%d\n", num);
>
>       //for float
>       System.out.println("Enter a float value: ");
>       num2 = sc.nextDouble();
>       ps.printf("%.2f\n", num2);
>
>       //for name w/o white space
>       System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
>       name = sc.next();
>       ps.printf("Hello %s, welcome to Scanner\n", name);
>
>
>       //for character
>       System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
>       c = sc.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
>       System.out.print(“%c”, c);
>
>       //for name w/ white space
>       System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
>       name = sc.nextLine();
>       System.out.print(“%s”, name);
>   }
> }
> ```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no need to wrap `System.out` in a `PrintStream` because `out` already supports formatting with `format()` or `printf()` methods.

Next, you need to understand that when you input a line of data you also terminate it with a *new line* `\n`. The `next<Type>()` methods only consume the `<Type>` and nothing else. So, if a `next<Type>()` call may match `\n`, you need to skip over any extra *new lines* `\n` with another `nextLine()` before.

Here's your code with fixes:

```
  int num;
  double num2;
  String name;
  char c;

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  //for integer
  System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
  num = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.printf("%d\n", num);

  //for float
  System.out.print("Enter a float value: ");
  num2 = sc.nextDouble();
  System.out.printf("%.2f\n", num2);

  //for name w/o white space
  System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
  name = sc.next();
  System.out.printf("Hello %s, welcome to Scanner\n", name);

  //for character
  System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
  c = sc.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
  System.out.printf("%c\n", c);

  sc.nextLine(); // skip

  //for name w/ white space
  System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
  name = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.printf("%s", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  //for a single char
  char Character = sc.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

  //for a name with white space
  System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
      String name2 = sc.next();
      String surname = sc.next();
      System.out.println(name2 + " " + surname);
```

Comment: when I run the program, sc.nextLine doesn't allow me to scan, it ends the program right away.

Comment: there was no error message.. it goes like this
Enter a character: a
a
Enter your full name: 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds) I wasnt able to type in the last scanner

Comment: In short, the sc.nextLine doesn't work for scanning my string. -_-

Comment: It's confusing, but sc.nextLine() makes a mess. This works, I've tried that:         System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
       String name2 = sc.next();
       String surname = sc.next();
       System.out.println(name2 + " " + surname);

Comment: And a good advice - instead of PrintStream use System.out.print(); unless you want to write on a disc. If I helped, please, accept this question.

Comment: Thank you! It requires 15 reps to vote up, I only had 10. Hihi. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scanner.next(Pattern)` and pass `Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]")` to let scanner accept only 1 character defined.
 You can pass any regex as argument and check for [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)
 `Scanner.next();` for next line with spaces